# How to prevent wrapping of button in div

Tags: html, css

On a search page, there is a text input with a submit button to the right. When zooming in, the submit button actually goes on top of the search bar, because there is no room. Is there any way I can prevent the button from moving when it is out of room?

HTML

```
<input type="text">
<input type="submit">
```

Comment: Post your HTML and CSS. Or post a jfiddle demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Why are you zooming in? and if it doesn't move, then what would you expect to happen instead? :\

Comment: Here is a fiddle to get you asking the right questions: http://jsfiddle.net/PMXPw/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to wrap your `input` elements inside a `wrapper` and give it `fixed` `width`.

Take a look at the example => <kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5Uh35/1/)**</kbd>

**HTML**

```
<!--This is the wrapper element-->
<div class='wrapper'>
<input type="text">
<input type="submit">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper{
    width:200px; /*fixed width, so if the window is resized (zoomed in/out), it won't break*/
    height:40px;    
}

.wrapper input[type="text"]{
    width:100px;
    height:inherit;
    border:1px solid red;    
}

.wrapper input[type="submit"]{
    width:90px;
    height:inherit;
    border:1px solid brown;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While it's hard to answer without the code, but hope it helps:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="query"></td>
        <td><input type="submit"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Not so nice and I don't like it myself, but it works in any situation.